# Open responsive view from Firefox WebExtension

Tags: firefox, responsive-design, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a legacy add-on for firefox, that opened tabs in responsive view. To achieve this, I used the functions from the responsive design module available in

```
try { Components.utils.import("resource://devtools/client/responsivedesign/responsivedesign.jsm", respdsgn);
} catch (e) {
    try { Components.utils.import("resource:///modules/devtools/responsivedesign.jsm", respdsgn);
    } catch (e) {
        respdsgn = null;
    }
}
```

From what I understand, this is no longer possible using the new web extensions api. Is there an alternative api available to turn the responsive view on for a specific tab? Or is it still possible to use the old style somehow?

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old style (or a variant) cannot be used to open the responsive view. An API to open the reponsive view doesn't exist (yet) in WebExtensions and there is no feature request pending. If you want, you can create one here: http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/

(select WebExtensions - Untriaged as product)

The closest thing to achieve the same result, is implement the responsive design mode yourself. This shouldn't be hard to do, since you just have to change the width and the height of the "html" element.

Content script:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].width = "250px";
```

Good luck!

Comment: I was fearing this. I'll try with the workaround and see if this will be enough for our use case..